# Hash Table With Chaining Search Time?

Tags: linked-list, hashtable

If I implement a hash table, I understand that the insertion is done in constant time. I also understand I can find the item in constant time if there is no collision. However, if I insert an item and chain it using a linked list in some arbitrary index and it ends up being in position 2, but it's linked 3 links down the list, is this O(n) time, for searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a misunderstanding of O(n) time. Big-O analysis has to do with the general case, not a specific instance. Intuitively, think of your hash table doing thousands or millions of lookups over time and taking a step back and judging if it's doing what a hash table is supposed to do.

If you had a completely degenerate hash table that hashed everything to the same slot, you would have O(n) lookup performance.

If n >> m where n is the number of elements stored, and m is the size of the hash table, your hash table lookup performance will degrade to O(n).

In general the performance of the hash table relates to the *average* chain length. If this average is a (small) constant, such that it is *not* a function of n, you have the desired O(1) lookup performance.